# on_press_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'

Tags: python

```
while True:
    if keyboard.on_press_key('a'):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("test")
```

выдает:

```
File "c:\Users\PC-TV\Desktop\Minecraft Bot\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    if keyboard.on_press_key('a'):
TypeError: on_press_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: Что такое `keyboard`? Из какой библиотеки? Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на документацию, которой вы руководствовались, когда писали этот код.

Comment: TypeError: on_press_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
Методу не хватает 1 позиционного аргумента.
Из кода библиотеки:
def on_press_key(key, callback, suppress=False):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_press_key` ожидает от Вас получить 3 аргумента `key, callback, suppress`. Обязательными являются 2 `key` и `callback`, а третий по умолчанию равен `False`. В Вашем случае указан только один 1 аргумент.
Ваш код можно написать следующим образом и он должен работать:

```
import keyboard

def print_test():
    print('test')
while True:
   keyboard.on_press_key('f', print_test)
```

Пробуйте

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard


def test():
    print('test')
    
keyboard.on_press_key('a', test())
```

Comment: В `on_press_key` `test()` без скобок должен быть, а то так вы сразу функцию `test` вызываете

Comment: а если перед этим будет переменна с таким именем?

Comment: Не понял вашу мысль. Если в тексте будет ещё и переменная `test`, то у питона этой переменной ссылка на функцию перетрётся и он в любом случае не сможет потом функцию вызвать, скобки никак не помогут. В питоне так нельзя, чтобы разные штуки имели одно название, у него всё в одной куче лежит.